# Power series method for differential equation $x^2y''+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I tried to solve $(x^2)y''+y=0$ using power series, but I cannot get the general solution or the relation at least

$$(x^2)y''+y=0 $$

$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty c_n n(n-1) x^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$$

$$ \sum_{k=2}^\infty c_k k(k-1) x^k + \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k$$

$$ c_o+c_1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty c_k (k^2-k+1) x^k$$

From here $C_0=0$, $C_1=0$, $ C_k(k^2 -k+1)=0$.

Is this right? How can I get a recurrence relation for coefficients or the general solution of the series?

Comment: Put your work in the question. The comments are not part of the question. (For one thing, people who know how to format math for this site can't format your comment so others can read it...)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: First, are my solution correct???, if right? I cannot formulate  recurrence relation, then I cannot find C3,C4...... to formulate close expression for the general solution of power series.

Comment: Whoa... You've got $x,X,k,K,$and $N$ to boot. Be consistent. You can write subscripts with the underscore like c_0 to $c_0$. Also your fourth line actually implies that $c_0 + c_1 = 0 \implies c_0 = -c_1$. And since the equation is singular at $x=0$ when written in general form, perhaps a Frobenius series may give you the actual solution, not a standard pwoer series.

Comment: Just a minor detail : the expansion would be $c_0+c_1x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty c_k (k^2-k+1) x^k=0$ which leads to all $c_i=0$. This means that you cannot expand as series.

Comment: thanks for your help. Actually No, $ C_0=0, C_1=0$

Comment: I know, this What I conclude, But My professor, said it can be solved by Analytically method?? I don't how??  I Just tried to ask people before I will go to discuss with him the issue.

Comment: Perhaps your professor means the other method for solving Euler-Cauchy equations, setting $x=e^t$, $u(t)=y(e^t)$ so that you get a linear DE with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

First rearrange $x^2y''+y=0$ to

$$y''+\frac{1}{x^2}y=0$$

Since the equation has a [regular singular point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularSingularPoint.html) a likely [plan of attack](http://Frobenius%20Method) assumes $y = \sum\limits_{n= 0}^\infty c_n x^{n+p}$ where $p$ is yet to be determined. Taking derivatives and substituting above gives

$$\sum\limits_{n= 0}^\infty (n+p)(n+p-1)c_n x^{n+p-2}+\frac{1}{x^2}\sum\limits_{n= 0}^\infty c_n x^{n+p}=0$$

$$\sum\limits_{n= 0}^\infty \bigg\{(n+p)(n+p-1) +1\bigg\} c_n x^{n+p-2}=0$$

For $n=0$, we have the lowest power of $x$. It's coefficient is $\big\{p(p-1)+1 \big\}c_0$. This *must* equal zero if the equation is to equal zero for any $x$. For a nontrivial solution, $c_0 \ne 0$. Then

$$\big\{p(p-1)+1 \big\}c_0=0$$
$$p^2-p+1=0$$

This has complex roots $p_{1,2} = \frac{1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, which implies that $y$ is a complex series where $c_n \in \mathbb{C}$. Substituting our roots back into the assumed form for $y$, this implies that the solutions have form

$$y = x^{p1}\sum\limits_{n= 0}^\infty c_n x^{n} \quad \mathtt{and} \quad y = x^{p2}\sum\limits_{n= 0}^\infty c_n x^{n}$$

There is a good deal of analysis that actually winds up with a generalized form for such a case! Solutions to the Frobenius equation with complex indicial roots are given by a general solution where the roots are $p_{1,2} = a +ib$:

$$y_1 = (x-x_0)^{a}\cos\left(b \ln|x-x_0| \right)$$
$$y_2 = (x-x_0)^{a}\sin\left(b \ln|x-x_0| \right)$$

where $x_0$ is the singular point. For us $x_0 = 0$, so for our roots we have

$$y_1 = A x^{1/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln|x| \right)$$
$$y_2 = B x^{1/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln|x| \right)$$

This matches [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2y%27%27%2By%3D0). I recommend researching the Frobenius Method where the indicial roots are complex for further information.

Comment: I was just writing in the same direction ! Good shot. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Hah thanks. I gave in to the general solution when I realized the roots were complex, though! I figure a textbook explanation is the obvious next step.

Comment: thanks guys for your valuable help.

Comment: This is incorrect: "Solutions to the Frobenius equation with complex indicial roots are given by a general solution where the roots are $p_{1,2} = a +ib$: $y_1 = A x^{1/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln|x| \right) y_2 = (x-x_0)^{a}\sin\left(b \ln|x-x_0| \right)$." Take this as an example: $x^2y''-3y'+4y=0$. The solution is clearly not expressed in this form. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2y%27%27-3y%27%2B4y%3D0. The reason this differential equation has such a neat form is because it is the Cauchy-Euler equation without the middle term.